# MS ACCESS SQL query to find all the columns that are of the type Datatime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have to find all the columns in a table where the datatype for that column is datetime.

Any ideas on how to do this?

IE

```
 Select * FROM Table1 WHERE datatype = datetime.
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (please add this as a tag to your question)

Comment: You'll need to query the metadata dictionary which is implemented differently depending on the dbms you use

Comment: Have a look here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/09/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-column-with-specific-data-types/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go for MS SQL Server:

```
select c.name as table_name, a.name as column_name
from sys.columns a
join sys.types b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
join sys.tables c on a.object_id = c.object_id
where b.name = 'datetime'
and c.type = 'U'
```

Note that there are other datatypes that can hold dates: date, datetime2, datetimeoffset. To get all of then change `WHERE` clause to:

```
where b.name in ('datetime', 'date', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset')
```

OR

```
where b.name like 'date%'
```

**UPDATE**

`Timestamp`  is:

> Returns the value of the current timestamp data type for the current database. This timestamp is guaranteed to be unique in the database. Returns **varbinary**.

It has nothing to do with date, time or storing arbitrary data in it. It more a sequential unique key (like GUID).

Comment: `timestamp` is nothing to do with dates and times despite the name.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful, could you refer me to where you find this information? ie is there any documentation? I hate having to ask on stack overflow.

Comment: do you know how I could check for multiple datatypes? Ie datetime and datetime2?

Comment: Just alter `WHERE` cluse. Get list of datatypes by `select * from sys.types`

Comment: Is there any way i can also display the value of the date fields if they are before 1 certain date? IE. Display all dates before 1900?

Comment: @AntonHughes What if there are many such rows in the table, do you want to see all of them or oldest date or smth else?

Comment: @MartinSmith I want to basically find all fields in a database which are datetime/datetime2 and which hold a date value before 1990. With each value, I need the table they came from with the associated field name. With your code above, we have the table name and field name....I just need the value to show aswell if its before 1900.